# How can I active link in Navigation Bar when I click any item located in that bar?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, nav, navigationbar

I have a problem about changing the class attribute as active when I click any selected item in the navigation bar.

I wrote this js code which is shown below to implement this process but it didn't work.

Here is my **HeaderPartialView** part.

```
.... css files
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Here is my **_Layout.cshtml** part.

```
....
@{
Html.RenderAction("HeaderPartial", "Home");
}

@{
    Html.RenderAction("NavbarPartial", "Home");
}  

....
@{
   Html.RenderAction("JSFilesPartial", "Home");
}
```

Here is my **JSFilesPartial** files.

```
<script src="~/Content/SiteLayout/assets/js/navigation-bar.js"></script>
```

Here is my **navigation-bar.js** file.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var current = location.pathname;
        $('.navigation-bar li a').each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);

            if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
                $this.addClass('active');
            }
        })
    });
```

Here is **NavbarPartial** file.

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
      <ul class="navigation-bar">
           <li><a class="active" href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="/Home/About Us">About Us</a></li>
           <li><a href="/Home/Projects">Projects</a></li>
      </ul>
    <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
</nav><!-- .navbar -->
```

How can I fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Navbar

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar">
            <ul class="navigation-bar">
                <li><a href="/Home/Index">AnaSayfa</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Hakkimizda">Hakkımızda</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Hizmetler">Hizmetler</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Content/SiteLayout/portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Content/SiteLayout/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/BizKimiz">Biz Kimiz</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Home/Iletisim">Bize Ulaşın</a></li>
            </ul>
            <i class="bi bi-list mobile-nav-toggle"></i>
        </nav><!-- .navbar -->
```

Js file

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var current = location.pathname;

    $('.navigation-bar li a').each(function () {
        
        var $this = $(this);

        if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
            $this.addClass('active');
        }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  $(".somClass li a").on('click', (e) => {
    $(".somClass li a").removeClass('active');
    $(e.target).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="somClass">
  <li><a class="active" href="#">link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Since you have active class as prop of anchor element you should try with `.navigation-bar li a` instead

Answer (score 0):

You're adding the `active` class on the `li` element. It should be adding to the `a` element instead. The following should work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".navigation-bar li a").on("click", function () {
            $(".navigation-bar li a").removeClass("active");
            $(this).addClass("active");
        });
    });

</script>
```

But it will fail because you're switching pages, and the javascript is reloaded every time you click in a anchor element.

**I think this is what you're looking for:**

```
var current = location.pathname;
$('.navigation-bar li a').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    
    if($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1){
        $this.addClass('active');
    }
})
```

It basically searches with navigation element is currently active, adding the `active` class on the `a` element.

Comment: The HTML/JS code you provided intially only works if the href is within the current page, for example: 

`<a href="#projects">Projects</a>`.

Since you're changing pages - meaning you're in **Home (/Home/Index)** then click on **Projects (/Home/Projects)**, the code will go back to its initial state because you're switching pages.

Comment: How can I fix the issue which the code goes back to its initial state?

Comment: I updated my answer as well. Please see if it works according to your needs.

Comment: I tried your js code but it didn't work.  I updated my post again. Can you write full js code?

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: There is only an error. Here it is : SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'. Where is the problem?

Comment: This error is probably not related to the code I posted, and you won't need additional JS, the code i wrote previously should be just fine. I can't point exactly where the problem is, but i would guess one of these two things: 
1. one of your pages (Projects, About Us) is not returning the expected format or doesn't exist, meaning the `href` is incorrect;
2. one of your `<script>` source (`src`) is incorrect.
I think the most likely is the 2nd option. Check the `src` paths to your JavaScript files to make sure it is correct, it may be referecing a file that doesn't exist.

Comment: At last I ran the code but there is only problem. Home link is still active when I click another navbar item. How can I fix it?

Comment: So it worked? The home link is still active because you have  the `active` class hard coded in your HTML code, just remove it. It should be like this to work properly: `... <li><a href="/Home/Index">Home</a></li> ...`